# How to add language translation in JSON file in prestashop

Tags: php, json, prestashop

I use PS1.6 and it uses two languages. So, ho to make this work inside JSON file "block-cart-json.tpl"

This way is not working (add to cart popup window is not showing):

```
"condition": {if $product.condition|json_encode == 'used'}{l s='Used'}{elseif $product.condition|json_encode == 'new'}{l s='New'}{elseif $product.condition|json_encode == 'online'}{l s='Online'}{/if},
```

This way it works:

```
"condition": {$product.condition|json_encode}
```

However how can I sole my problem with multi language translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `blockcart.php` in `assignContentVars` method something like:

```
foreach ($products as &$product) {
    switch ($product['condition']) {
        case 'new':
            $product['product_condition'] = $this->l('New');
        break;

        case 'used':
            $product['product_condition'] = $this->l('Used');
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to modify block-cart-json.tpl you may need to add `mod='blockcart'` to your translations.

Also, i'm not sure if logic of your `{if}`s is correct. It would be much easier to place this logic in blockcart.php (you can do that as an override) and assign already translated variable to your .tpl file.

Comment: to mage it as a public function in "blockcart.php " is a great idea. I thought about it before. But my php skills don't allow me to do that. I feel like I am going around all time by the right solution, perhaps I cant manage to get it. Can you please give me a hint of how to do it?